# Date Field Mixed (Date and Text) Formatting

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I've had a look around and can't find an actual answer to this.

I have a .csv to download every day. In it includes a text field 7+2 digits long. The 7 digits are in format CYYMMDD and the 2 digits are blank spaces.

This would be today's date: `"1190729  "` (without the quotes)

I've tried about 20 ways to convert this to a regular date, but I can't get every record to update properly

So far

1. The QueryTable uses type 2 (Text)
2. I `=TRIM` the text, place it back in the same location
3. I change the text into a recognisable date
4. "Paste as Text"
5. Then I get the same thing every time. Any date where the DAY is 13 or more, is a text field. 12 and under is a date field
6. The best way to fix it is to `F2` but this is meant to be a totally automated report

I have tried changing `dd/mm/yyyy` to every other version I can think of (as for my excel `m/d/yyyy` is the default)

I've also tried moving `.Value = .Value` to the bottom, putting it in twice etc. but to no avail

[image]

```
Private Sub CopyDateTime(ByVal lastRowBeforeImport As Long)

Dim ws As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim tempsheet As String
Dim lastRowAfterImport, lastRowTemp
Set ws = Worksheets("Report")

'Bottom populated cell of Column "B"
lastRowAfterImport = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

    tempsheet = "temp"

Worksheets.Add
ActiveSheet.Name = tempsheet

Set ws2 = Worksheets("temp")
    With ws.Range(ws.Cells(lastRowBeforeImport, 5), ws.Cells(lastRowAfterImport, 6))
        'Copy new date and time to tempsheet'
        .Copy Destination:=ws2.Range("A1")
    End With

lastRowTemp = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

    With ws2.Range(Cells(1, 3), Cells(lastRowTemp, 3))
        .FormulaR1C1 = "=TRIM(RC[-2])"
        .Value = .Value
        .Copy Destination:=ws2.Range("A1")
        .Delete
    End With

    With ws2.Range(Cells(1, 3), Cells(lastRowTemp, 3))
        .FormulaR1C1 = "=RIGHT(RC[-2],2)&""/""&MID(RC[-2],4,2)&""/20""&MID(RC[-2],2,2)"
        .Value = .Value
        .NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
    End With


    With ws2.Cells(1, 4)
        .FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(TEXT(RC[-2],""000000""),3,2)&"":""&LEFT(TEXT(RC[-2],""000000""),2)&"":""&RIGHT(RC[-2],2)"
    End With

    'Delete tempsheet'
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    'Worksheets(tempsheet).Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I'd suggest using `DATE` instead of concatenating the month, day and year with slashes.

Comment: Have you played around with `DateValue`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have "1190729  " in A2 then the formula

```
=DATE(2000+(MID(A2,2,2)),(MID(A2,4,2)),(RIGHT(TRIM(A2),2)))
```

will produce the date 29th July 2019 in your current date format

Comment: Closest to what I was looking for. Just changed this to R1C1 notation and it's perfect!
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/date-data-type):

> Date variables are stored as IEEE 64-bit (8-byte) floating-point
>   numbers that represent dates ranging from 1 January 100, to 31
>   December 9999, and times from 0:00:00 to 23:59:59.

Your VBA function may parse well string formats from CSV, but you are creating a string value which is not a proper Excel data type for dates.

Use `=DATEVALUE` function to convert the string representation of the DATE (ex. 29/7/2019) to the actual Excel date.
For example in your case: `cell.Value = DATEVALUE(TRIM(RC[-2]))`

Once in the proper data type, you can change the date format using the `NumberFormat` property.

More about [DATEVALUE from MSDN](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/convert-dates-stored-as-text-to-dates-8df7663e-98e6-4295-96e4-32a67ec0a680).

Comment: Hi, thanks very much for this. great resource and I didn't know about datevalue before now